# Get set of arguments as result of a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I do not know the name of this pattern or even if it is exist. I need a function that return a set of arguments that would be used in another function. For example, I have this function:

```
void foo(int a, float b, some_class c);
```

I want to write a function like this:

```
//Theoretical code:
arguments get_arguments(){
    return arguments(0,0.0f, some_class());
}
```

Then call `foo` like this:

```
foo(get_arguments());
```

Is this possible? if yes,How?

Comment: Why does it need to be passed through the return value? An alternative would be to pass `a`, `b` and `c` by reference to `get_arguments` and then you can simply call `foo(a, b, c)`. Going through tuples just to have it as a return value or using std::apply seems unnecessary for a static case as this, no?

Comment: what is the different between calling foo directly and your solution?

Comment: the difference is that you delegate the responsibility to fill the parameters to another function, that's exactly what you're asking in your question, no?

Comment: Actually not.. I just need to get the arguments in another function. I would love to call foo directly using the notation I provided in my question

Comment: You could always create a data type for this:
`struct foo_context{int a; float b; some_class c;};`. `get_arguments` can return such a struct and you can then create a wrapper around `foo` which takes `void foo(foo_context& ctx)`.
It makes sense to keep these things clear so if your function gets its context (ie parameter) from another function, why not encapsulate that context?

Comment: @PatrikH yes you are right. But I was looking for generic solution that may work without any edit/add on the original function which is not possible till c++17 or (experimental)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_arguments` can be implemented with `std::make_tuple`:

```
auto get_arguments(){
    return std::make_tuple(0,0.0f, some_class());
}
```

This will return a `std::tuple<int,float,some_class>`.

You can call `foo` with the arguments using `std::experimental::apply` from C++17:

```
std::experimental::apply(foo, get_arguments());
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e45a9c6efe5d34f9)

There is an implementation of `std::experimental::apply` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply) if you need one.

---

To clean up the call, you could add a forwarding function:

```
template <typename Tuple>
void foo(Tuple&& t) {
    return std::experimental::apply(
        static_cast<void(*)(int,float,some_class)>(&foo),
        std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}
```

Then you can use the syntax you desire:

```
foo(get_arguments());
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed6ab52e8a0286ba)

Answer (score 9):

It could probably be done by using [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and overloading the `foo` function to take a tuple and expand it to call the actual `foo` function.

Comment: maybe in combination with [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi You don't have to edit the *original* `foo` function, just create a new overload of it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I understand that but if it is a std function it would be a problem.. or I have to build a wrapper function above it

Comment: There's nothing wrong with building a wrapper function.

Answer (score 7):

If your compiler supports future C++17 addition, you can do this by modifying `get_arguments()` to return `std::tuple` and using [`std::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
std::apply(foo, get_arguments())
```

Comment: That is really nice! Unfortunately no C++17 is available but many thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code using tuple, as I see now it bases on other ideas from this question:

[[live]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a73a1ddecfb641aa)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct some_class{};

void foo(int a, float b, some_class c) {
    std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
}

decltype(auto) get_arguments() {
   return std::make_tuple(0.1f, 0.2f, some_class{});
}

template<typename T>
void callFoo(const T& args)
{
  foo(std::get<0>(args), std::get<1>(args), std::get<2>(args));
}

int main()
{
    callFoo(get_arguments());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you ask... but... just for fun... using `std::bind` and `std::ref`, you can call `foo()` using a binded `bar()`, in this way

```
#include <tuple>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo(int a, float b, std::complex<double> c)
 { std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << std::endl; }

std::tuple<int, float, std::complex<double>> getArgs1 ()
 { return std::make_tuple(1, 22.22f, std::complex<double>{333.333, 4444.4444}); }

std::tuple<int, float, std::complex<double>> getArgs2 ()
 { return std::make_tuple(4444, 333.333f, std::complex<double>{22.22, 1.1}); }

int main()
 {

   std::tuple<int, float, std::complex<double>>  t;

   auto bar = std::bind(foo,
                        std::ref(std::get<0>(t)),
                        std::ref(std::get<1>(t)),
                        std::ref(std::get<2>(t)));

   t = getArgs1();

   bar();

   t = getArgs2();

   bar();

   return 0;
 }
```

The output is

```
a = 1, b = 22.22, c = (333.333,4444.44)
a = 4444, b = 333.333, c = (22.22,1.1)
```

I repeat: just for fun.

Answer (score 2):

`std::tuple` allows you to pack together the arguments you need for your call to `foo`. As others already pointed out, there are several ways you can then call your function and some of these might require a more recent standard.

In C++11, you already have `std::bind` which should suit your needs just fine in your case. Here's an example of how this could be achieved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

class MyClass {};

std::tuple<int, float, MyClass> get_arguments()
{
    int a = 0;
    float b = 1.0f;
    MyClass c;
    // ... calculate parameters;
    return std::make_tuple(a, b, c);
}

void foo(int a, float b, MyClass c)
{
    std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // get tuple holding arguments
    auto arguments = get_arguments();

    // Binding arguments and calling directly
    std::bind(
            foo, 
            std::get<0>(arguments), 
            std::get<1>(arguments), 
            std::get<2>(arguments))();

    return 0;
}
```

You can put the `std::bind` call into a wrapper, especially when you're using it frequently.

If you end up passing around packs of parameters back and forth, it might make sense to encapsulate them into their own data type or even a function  object. This method does not need `std::tuple` nor `std::bind` and can thus be used even when you don't have access to C++11.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {};

void foo(int a, float b, MyClass c)
{
    std::cout << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b << "\n";
}

class FooCaller
{
public:
    void operator()(void) const
    {
        foo(a, b, c);
    }

    int a;
    float b;
    MyClass c;
};

void get_arguments(FooCaller& fooCaller)
{
    // ... calculate parameters;
    fooCaller.a = 0.0f;
    fooCaller.b = 1.0f;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Create Instance and calculate/retrieve arguments
    FooCaller fooCaller;
    get_arguments(fooCaller);

    // call 'foo'
    fooCaller();
    return 0;
}
```

This could be made more generic but this might require some template metaprogramming features introduced in C++11 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to achieve the same things

1. Plain old C++ way : Return a structure containing multiple variables
2. C++11 Way : use std::tuples
3. Boost Way : Use boost::fusion

The best way to declare return type of function as "auto"